# Lookup tables in 8051 microcontroller

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, lookup-tables, 8051

When I'm executing this code, the answer is A=20H. Can anyone explain to me why. Or another example where MOV A, #08H ---> result A=70H.

```
org 00h
MOV A,#03H
MOVC A,@A+PC
SJMP $
DB 10H, 20H, 30H, 40H, 50H, 60H, 70H, 80H
end
```

Comment: Which part needs explanation? `PC` points to next instruction, that is `SJMP $` which is 2 bytes. So if `A=0` you index the `SJMP` opcode, `A=1` is the offset, `A=2` is the first `DB` entry of `10H` and so on.